# Vanilla nodeJs redirect to another page

Tags: node.js, redirect, relocation

I am using vanilla node without any framework and I can't seem to redirect to another page.So far I have tried

```
const server = require('http');
server.createServer(
function (req, res) {
   if (req.url == '/') {
      // do stuff
      res.end();
   } 
   else if (req.url == '/signIn') {
      res.writeHead(302, { Location: '/signIn' });
      res.end();
   }

}).listen(8080);
```

I have also used 301 but to no avail. I can easily read from the file and display it's contents like so

```
const server = require('http');
const fileSys = require('fs');
fileSys.readFile('./signIn.html', function (err, html) {
server.createServer(function (req, res) {
    if (req.url == '/') {            
        //do something
    } 
    
    else if (req.url == '/signIn') {

      res.writeHead(200, { 'content-type': 'text/html'});
      res.write(html);
      res.end();   
    }
})
  .listen(8080);
```

});

But I don't want that. I have seen that it can be done easily with help of express. Is vanilla node not right tool for routing? "signin" is a simple html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <body background="blue">
            <h1>Sign In here!</h1>
                <p>Enter your Information</p>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: what sense does it make to redirect from `/signIn` to `/signIn`? That's a redirect loop which will probably detected by the browser. How would you expect the file to be sent to the client, if you "*don't want*"  to read it from disk?

Comment: @derpirscher I guess I am taking the wrong approach towards this problem, thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 0):

This should work, did you test if the req.url is actually '/signIn'? Also it would be better to use '===' instead of '==' so that you check for the specific type of the attribute.

Try to add a console.log, or use a debugger and let me know.

edit: I've tested your code locally and it seems to work fine?
I'm not sure what you're expecting here. What happens when I open a page in my browser it sees the req.url as "/" so it does nothing which is what you've coded. When I navigate to /signIn it opens the html page. You could add an else statement that also does the same as in the 'else if (req.url == '/signIn') ' ?

Comment: Thanks and sorry for late response,  I have tried your solution and yes I can see '/signin' in console. I have added more details to the question may be that would help.

Comment: No replies? It's a simple enough question I would really appreciate any form of help.